# Custom/simplified maps with OpenHeatMap and/or OpenStreetMap

Tags: mapping, openstreetmap, heatmap

I'm working on a project with [OpenHeatMap](http://www.openheatmap.com/), which overall seems like a great, simple well-executed project. It's meeting all my needs, except it relies on OpenStreetMap for its mapping, and I can't find a way to reduce the level of detail it presents. Ideally, I'd like it to simply show a very high-level view of one state, and keep out the clutter, but I can't find any way to do this on either OpenStreetMap or OpenHeatMap.

Any advice? OpenHeatMap allows you to set your map tile source, but I also couldn't find another source besides OSM.

Comment: Zooming out of the heat map doesn't reduce the clutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you meant something like that? http://www.tilecache.org/

Its the standard osGis-Style.

but I can't find any option to change the background of OpenHeatMap...

Answer (score 3):

*"I also couldn't find another source besides OSM"*.   Well there's many OpenStreetMap based renderings run by different people. There's a [few listed here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Tile_servers).

Try setting your map tile source to one of those. You may like the look of MapQuest's OpenStreetMap rendering for example. And with CloudMade you can actually design your own style (so drop some details you don't want)